# Add numbers in dialog box

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am new to android. I am developing an application for exam in which I want to show all question numbers in a dialog box so that the user can switch to any question i.e 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. I tried the following code but it is not proper. I am getting total no of questions from server example I have 40 questions so I want to show numbers from 1 to 40 in a dialog box. Please help

```
  AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                // Set an EditText view to get user input
                final TextView input = new TextView(context);
                input.setText("" + i);
                input.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                input.setTextSize(15);

                input.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String srt = "clickd";
                        Toast.makeText(context, srt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });
                layout.addView(input);
                alert.setView(layout);
            }
            alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    //You will get as string input data in this variable.
                    // here we convert the input to a string and show in a toast.
                    String srt = "fdsfdsf";
                    Toast.makeText(context, srt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } // End of onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
            }); //End of alert.setPositiveButton
            alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // Canceled.
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }); //End of alert.setNegativeButton
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
            alertDialog.show();
```

I have taken here 20 questions but it can be any no.  Something like this

[image]

Comment: why don't you use a listview inside the dialog

Comment: @VishalGaur I have posted an image. Please check. I want something like this

Comment: you should use Dialog fragment and create GridView  layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are trying to display fixed sized of data let say 20 numbers from the response.Simple way is that set up gridView inside your Dialog with fixed amount of data like this :

```
private void showDialog() {
    //Here is ur gridview
    GridView gridView = new GridView(ctx);

    List<Integer>  mList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 1 ; i < 20; i++) {
        mList.add(i);
    }

    gridView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(ctx, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mList));
    gridView.setNumColumns(4);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // do what ev you want with ur stuff here
        }
    });

    // Here you can set grid view to ur dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctxI);
    builder.setView(gridView);
    builder.setTitle("Its me !!");
    builder.show();
}
```